# Headless mode hits error, while Non-Headless Mode doesn't

Tags: selenium, wait, headless

I'm running my scripts in headless mode and I'm hitting errors that don't occur when I run the same script in Non-Headless mode. The "ExpectedConditions" lines keep hitting a "Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //div[@id='sidebar-top-item'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)" Errors

```
@Test (priority=2)
public void ChangePassword() {

    // Wait for Dashboard Button
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    WebElement dashButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Go To Dashboard')]")));
    dashButton.click();

    // Change Password
    WebElement proNameX = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='sidebar-top-item']")));
    proNameX.click();
    WebElement changePass = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='nf-change-password-btn']")));
    changePass.click();

    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='nf-change-password-btn']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("old_password")).sendKeys("Password");
    driver.findElement(By.name("new_password")).sendKeys("NewPassword");
    driver.findElement(By.name("new_password2")).sendKeys("NewPassword");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button']")).click();
    log.info("Password Change Completed");
```

[Dom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcdcn.png)

Any Ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What you have tried for headless mode can please mentioned in your post?

Comment: I've tried different kinds of Expected Conditions, but nothing seems to work 100% of the time. They randomly fail

Comment: I mean to say can you please post headless browser code so that OP can see what you have written for headless browser and the they might found some solution for you.

Comment: I've posted the headless code below, sorry

Comment: @KajalKundu Is the headless mode code incorrect? Thanks

Comment: headless mode looks correct.

Comment: I don't know your window screen size.Just increase the size and check any difference? `chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1920,1440")`

Comment: If works fine otherwise you have to share url to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my headless mode code for Chrome

```
        case "chromeheadless":
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1440,900");
            driver.set(new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions));
            break;
```